How can I styleing in next.js page only
I want to style in next but I can
let cursor = document.getElementById(".cursor");
cursor.style.display = "none";

I cant do any thing for this problem is, please, I want a solution as soon as possible I have tried many methods but they do not work

Can you please provide a sandbox for it . The question is not clear

I want to access into css but by page.tsx in next.js

Your question is unclear but to use let cursor = document.getElementById(".cursor"); cursor.style.display = "none"; you need to create a client side component, you cannot add that code directly inside a server component. Read this to know more about it.
